# What is apt downloading?

Tags: apt, kubuntu, 22.04, downloads

In the last few weeks I've been troubled by the following problem: everyday, `apt` automatically download something using maximum internet priority: it doesn't request any password. Given my slow internet connection, it usually takes 20-25minutes, in which I'm unable to load any webpage, let alone receive or send emails. The situation is unbearable.

This is a screenshot of the only information I have been able to gather.

[image]

Is there any way to get more information? I want to know what my system is downloading...

OS: Kubuntu 22.04.

Don't be afraid to ask any missing information.

**EDIT**:

This is the content of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
```

This is the content of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20-auto-upgrades`:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

This is the content of `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`. I believe the system might be downloading nvidia drivers and trying to install them and fails?

```
2023-07-08 20:30:18,153 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2023-07-08 20:30:18,153 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2023-07-08 20:45:42,470 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2023-07-08 20:45:42,470 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security, o=LP-PPA-mozillateam,a=jammy
2023-07-08 20:45:42,470 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2023-07-08 20:45:42,470 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2023-07-08 20:45:45,742 WARNING Package nvidia-kernel-common-525 has conffile prompt and needs to be upgraded manually
2023-07-08 20:45:46,238 INFO package libnvidia-cfg1-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:46,574 INFO package libnvidia-compute-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:46,879 INFO package libnvidia-compute-515:i386 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:47,192 INFO package libnvidia-decode-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:47,512 INFO package libnvidia-decode-515:i386 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:47,768 INFO package libnvidia-encode-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:48,027 INFO package libnvidia-encode-515:i386 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:48,285 INFO package libnvidia-extra-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:48,545 INFO package libnvidia-fbc1-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:48,799 INFO package libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:49,055 INFO package libnvidia-gl-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:49,309 INFO package libnvidia-gl-515:i386 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:49,563 INFO package nvidia-compute-utils-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:49,682 WARNING package nvidia-dkms-515 upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2023-07-08 20:45:49,898 WARNING package nvidia-dkms-515 upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2023-07-08 20:45:50,001 INFO package nvidia-dkms-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:50,119 WARNING package nvidia-driver-515 upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2023-07-08 20:45:50,338 WARNING package nvidia-driver-515 upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2023-07-08 20:45:50,443 INFO package nvidia-driver-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:50,662 INFO package nvidia-kernel-common-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:50,971 INFO package nvidia-kernel-source-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:51,244 INFO package nvidia-utils-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:51,557 INFO package xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 not upgraded
2023-07-08 20:45:51,663 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
2023-07-08 20:45:51,708 INFO Package libnvidia-cfg1-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,709 INFO Package libnvidia-compute-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,709 INFO Package libnvidia-compute-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,710 INFO Package libnvidia-decode-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,711 INFO Package libnvidia-decode-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,712 INFO Package libnvidia-encode-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,713 INFO Package libnvidia-encode-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,713 INFO Package libnvidia-extra-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,714 INFO Package libnvidia-fbc1-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,715 INFO Package libnvidia-fbc1-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,716 INFO Package libnvidia-gl-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,717 INFO Package libnvidia-gl-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,742 INFO Package nvidia-compute-utils-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,743 INFO Package nvidia-dkms-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,743 INFO Package nvidia-driver-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,744 INFO Package nvidia-kernel-common-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,745 INFO Package nvidia-kernel-source-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,746 INFO Package nvidia-utils-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
2023-07-08 20:45:51,767 INFO Package xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
```

The following screenshot shows that software updates are managed manually.

[image]

This is every source selected in the Discover application.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: APT auto-checks for updates daily. You can disable it, and check for updates manually whenever ready.

Comment: Do you mean auto-upgrades? I've added more information to the question, take a look...

Comment: Might this be a `snap` or even 'flathub' -related "problem"?  (I have disabled and removed snap, to much monkey business with those)

Comment: Maybe? Unfortunately I can't remove them, there are app that are only available with those channels.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the WinKey / Super key and type "Software", click on the pinkish icon that appears.

In there; Select the /Updates\ tab and set the options you wish for...

Comment: I've checked and manual updates are already selected. I've added a few more screenshot maybe it helps to debug...